# Fast Radial Symmetry Transform (FRST) implementation (python) results in unusual cross-hair looking artifacts

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, computational-geometry

I am trying to implement FRST on python to detect centroids of elliptical objects (e.g. cells in microscopy images), but my implementation does not find seed points (more or less center points) of elliptical objects. This effort comes from duplicating FRST from *Segmentation of Overlapping Elliptical Objects in Silhouette Images* (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7300433). I don't know why I have these artifacts. An interesting thing is that I see these patterns (crosses) all in the same direction per object. Any point in the right direction to generate the same result as in the paper (just to find the seed points) will be most welcome.

Original Paper: *A Fast Radial Symmetry Transform for Detecting Points of Interest* by Loy and Zelinsky (ECCV 2002)

I have also tried the pre-existing python package for FRST: https://pypi.org/project/frst/. This somehow results in the same artifacts. Weird.

1. First image: Original Image
2. Second image: Sobel-operated Image
3. Third image: Magnitude Projection Image
4. Fourth image: Magnitude Projection Image with positively affected pixels only
5. Fifth image: FRST'd image: end-product with original image overlaid (shadowed)
6. Sixth image: FRST'd image by the pre-existing python package with original image overlaid (shadowed).

[image: Original Image]
[image: Sobel-operated Image]
[image: Magnitude Projection Image]
[image: Magnitude Projection Image with positively affected pixels only]
[image: FRST'd image: end-product with original image overlaid (shadowed)]
[image: FRST pre-existing python package]

```
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve


# Get orientation projection image
def get_proj_img(image, radius):

    workingDims = tuple((e + 2*radius) for e in image.shape)

    h,w = image.shape

    ori_img = np.zeros(workingDims) # Orientation Projection Image
    mag_img = np.zeros(workingDims) # Magnitutde Projection Image 

    # Kenels for the sobel operator 
    a1 = np.matrix([1, 2, 1])
    a2 = np.matrix([-1, 0, 1])
    Kx = a1.T * a2
    Ky = a2.T * a1

    # Apply the Sobel operator
    sobel_x = convolve(image, Kx)
    sobel_y = convolve(image, Ky)
    sobel_norms = np.hypot(sobel_x, sobel_y)

    # Distances to afpx, afpy (affected pixels)    
    dist_afpx = np.multiply(np.divide(sobel_x, sobel_norms, out = np.zeros(sobel_x.shape), where = sobel_norms!=0), radius)
    dist_afpx = np.round(dist_afpx).astype(int)

    dist_afpy = np.multiply(np.divide(sobel_y, sobel_norms, out = np.zeros(sobel_y.shape), where = sobel_norms!=0), radius)
    dist_afpy = np.round(dist_afpy).astype(int)


    for cords, sobel_norm in np.ndenumerate(sobel_norms):
        i, j = cords

        pos_aff_pix = (i+dist_afpx[i,j], j+dist_afpy[i,j])
        neg_aff_pix = (i-dist_afpx[i,j], j-dist_afpy[i,j])

        ori_img[pos_aff_pix] += 1
        ori_img[neg_aff_pix] -= 1
        mag_img[pos_aff_pix] += sobel_norm
        mag_img[neg_aff_pix] -= sobel_norm

    ori_img = ori_img[:h, :w]
    mag_img = mag_img[:h, :w]

    print ("Did it go back to the original image size? ")
    print (ori_img.shape == image.shape)

    # try normalizing ori and mag img
    return ori_img, mag_img

def get_sn(ori_img, mag_img, radius, kn, alpha):

    ori_img_limited = np.minimum(ori_img, kn)
    fn = np.multiply(np.divide(mag_img,kn), np.power((np.absolute(ori_img_limited)/kn), alpha))

    # convolute fn with gaussian filter. 
    sn = gaussian_filter(fn, 0.25*radius)

    return sn

def do_frst(image, radius, kn, alpha, ksize = 3):
    ori_img, mag_img = get_proj_img(image, radius)
    sn = get_sn(ori_img, mag_img, radius, kn, alpha)

    return sn
```

Parameters:

```
radius = 50
kn = 10
alpha = 2
beta = 0 
stdfactor = 0.25
```

Comment: Did you look at the intermediate images `sobel_x` and `sobel_y` to verify they're correct? You might need to swap the two (the first index tends to be downward)?

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, that solved it! I switched sobel_x and sobel_y and it worked! I am still confused. I thought I did it right having Gx = sobel_x and Gy = sobel_y. I double-checked Kx and Ky and they are exactly as sobel operator is defined. Could you explain why they need to be switched?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Is it because the image indexing is actually done in the way that image [y_coordinate, x_coordinate]? I think I missed that in my implementation.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. You need to compute the derivative along the first indexing dimension and the second indexing dimension, not so much x and y. I mean it doesn’t matter which direction is x, it is about which derivative to use to increment or decrement each index.